# Get the position of each item in a single-dimension numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I need to multiply each element by it's position. 
What is the idiomatic way to get a position (index) of each element in a single-dimension numpy array?

The only idea I have is to use the second array with position numbers: `x * np.arange(np.size(x))`

P.S. Some elements could have similar values. So `np.where()` is not working good.

Comment: What's wrong with your approach of `x * np.arange(np.size(x))`. Seems perfectly fine to me

Comment: Was looking for simple way to refer the position numeber. Found also: `x * [i for i,x in enumerate(x)]` but it seems to be slower.

Comment: Yes because it uses pure python code